# Minha URL amigável não passa a variável por GET

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigável

Já dei uma olhada nas perguntas relacionadas a esse problema aqui no Stack e não obtive sucesso, atualmente estou conseguindo passar os valores pela URL mas não consigo chamar elas em outra página com GET. URL vai assim:

```
http://localhost/sustenagil/noticia/o-projeto-soja-mais-sustentavel/34/
```

Minha linha no .htaccess assim:

```
RewriteRule noticia/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/ noticia.php?id=$2 [NC]
```

Na noticia.php ta padrão:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Só que não vai, certeza que o problema é no .htaccess mas não consigo achar, já mudei praticamente a linha toda.

O erro que aparece é:

> "Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp64\www\sustenagil\noticia.php
>   on line 53"

Comment: `$_GET['id']` chegou nulo? Se não, o que aconteceu?

Comment: "Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp64\www\sustenagil\noticia.php on line 53"
Linha 53: $id = $_GET['id'];

Comment: Coloque o código para que possamos ajudar